# How to add text under image in html css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hello i have this website that must look like this:

[image]

this is an image of what i have done so far:

[image]

and this is my code:

```css
body {
            overflow-x: hidden;
          }
          .design {
            width: 771px;
            height: 568px;
            margin-left: 364px;
            margin-right: 365px;
            margin-top: 247px;
            margin-bottom: 200px;
          }
    
          .image1 {
            width: 138px;
            height: 92px;
            margin-top: 33px;
            margin-left: 24px;
            margin-right: 116px;
          }
    
          .image2 {
            width: 99px;
            height: 98px;
            margin-top: 35px;
            margin-left: 24px;
            margin-right: 81px;
          }
    
          .image3 {
            width: 79px;
            height: 90px;
            margin-top: 39px;
            margin-left: 25.7px;
            margin-right: 60px;
          }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Horseradish</title>
        <link
          href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-uWxY/CJNBR+1zjPWmfnSnVxwRheevXITnMqoEIeG1LJrdI0GlVs/9cVSyPYXdcSF"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
        <style>
          
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <header>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6"></div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="text-end">
                <img src="images/location.png" alt="" class="image1" />
                <img src="images/how.png" alt="" class="image2" />
                <img src="images/why.png" alt="" class="image3" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    
        </header>
        <img src="images/home.png" alt="" class="design" />
      </body>
    </html>
```

I have put the images in the correct way but i am stuck adding the text below the image. I have also added bootstrap. Any suggestions how to do it would be helpful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take a look at bootstrap and how it works ( if you say you want to use bootstrap. You can use flexbox without bootstrap too ) . Add both img and text in a column.
Do not use stuff like ` margin-left: 364px;` . Use percentages or viewport units. If you want to have a nice responsive website. Check : ' responsive design patterns ' on the web. You have a bit of work to do to read some documentation and understand some concepts. But it will help you a lot in the future. Good luck

Comment: Take a look to [figure tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure?retiredLocale=it)

Comment: @MihaiT I also do not want to use margins but this is a requirement that I cannot avoid.

Comment: Yes, you can avoid . You can position them in a different way.  Consider you have a screen of 700px width. How will `margin-left: 364px;` work there ? Not mentioning mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

As a simple approach, you can make use of `figure` and `figcaption`, and then apply your styles to figcaption.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_figcaption

In case you want to move your text a little bit up like one in the image with the horse, you can use the `position` property.

Answer (score 0):

Tweaked your code a bit, you can try something like this using bootstrap :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>
      .design {
        width: 771px;
        height: 568px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="d-block text-center">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=4" class="design" alt=""  />
    <p class="text-center">Hello</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try learning about flexbox. Is it much easier to understand and to play with too.
Hope this is what you asked for.
Here's the snippet code:

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  padding:15px;
flex-wrap:wrap;
}
img{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
.cnt1, .cnt2, .cnt3{
  margin:15px;
  padding:0;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column; 
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="cnt1">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/dQrHQVKX/download.jpg">
<h5>pic1</h5>
</div>

<div class="cnt2">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/dQrHQVKX/download.jpg">
<h5>pic1</h5>
</div>

<div class="cnt3">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/dQrHQVKX/download.jpg">
<h5>pic1</h5>
</div>

</div>
```